# How can I specify 1 api routes with 2 differents query combination options

Tags: javascript, node.js, soajs

How can I specify 1 api routes with 2 differents query combination options

We have 2 routes:

```
  GET /api/v1/resource?filter=byName&key=restaurant&city=chicago
  GET /api/v1/resource?filter=byLocation&lat=34&long=78
```

In `soaJS`, we described our schemas like this:

// File config.js

```
  module/exports = {
     type: 'service',
     ...
     schemas: {
      ...
        commonFields: {
             filter: {
                 source: ["query.filter"],
                 required: true,
                 validation: {
                     type: "string",
                     enum: ["byName", "byLocation"]
                 }
             },
             key: {
                 source: ["query.key"],
                 required: true,
                 validation: {
                     type: "string"
                 }
             },
             lat: {
                 source: ["query.lat"],
                 required: true,
                 validation: {
                     type: "number"
                 }
             },
             long: {
                 source: ["query.long"],
                 required: true,
                 validation: {
                     type: "number"
                 }
             },
             ... // city

        },
    get: {
         "/api/v1/resource": {
                "_apiInfo": {
                   "l": "get resource by ?",
                   "m": "get"
                },
                "commonFields": [ ? ],
             }
        ...
 }
```

When `filter=byName`, then `key` is mandatory, ...

When `filter=byLocation`, then `lat` is mandatory, ...

How should we handle these two routes differences within **soajs** route definitions in respect of the REST philosophy ?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOAJS IMFV is based on json schema. You can achieve this by using oneOf. Please checkout this URL https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/

here is how you can do it:

```
{
   schema : {
      post : {
         "/imfvOneOf": {
            "_apiInfo": {
                "l": "Example of IMFV & oneOf",
                "group": "Basic"
            },
            "data": {
                "source": ["body.data"],
                "required": true,
                "validation": {
                    "oneOf": [
                        {
                            filter: {
                                required: true,
                                type: "string",
                                enum: ["byName"]
                            },
                            key: {
                                required: true,
                                type: "string"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            filter: {
                                required: true,
                                type: "string",
                                enum: ["byLocation"]
                            },
                            lat: {
                                required: true,
                                type: "number"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            long: {
                source: ["body.long"],
                required: true,
                validation: {
                    type: "number"
                }
            }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: its been a long time.  Not working on that issue anymore... So accepting this answer.